# Issues with Esquisse Package Integration in Shiny Data Visualization App

Tags: shiny, visualization

I am developing a Shiny app that allows the user to upload an XLSX file and then randomly select 20% of the data. Afterward, the app sends that same dataset to the Esquisse tab, where the user can create data visualizations without the need for coding.

The app is functioning properly in terms of file upload and random data selection. However, the issue appears to be related to the Esquisse package, as I'm not seeing any content within the Esquisse tab. What could be causing this problem?

the UI :

```
# Chargez les bibliothèques requises
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(esquisse)


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Application Shiny",
             tabPanel("Data",
                      fileInput("file", "Télécharger un fichier Excel"),
                      DTOutput("data_table")
             ),
             tabPanel(    title = "esquisse",
                          esquisse_ui(
                            id = "esquisse", 
                            header = FALSE
             )
  )
))
```

the server :

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    df <- read.xlsx(input$file$datapath, 1, col_names = TRUE)
    colnames(df) <- paste0(colnames(df), "_")
    df
  })
  
 
  subsample_data <- reactive({
    data_all <- data()
    sample_size <- round(0.2 * nrow(data_all))
    sample_data <- data_all[sample(1:nrow(data_all), sample_size), ]
    return(sample_data)
  })
  
  output$data_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(subsample_data())
  })
  

  data_rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL, name = 'data')
  
  observeEvent(subsample_data, {
    data_rv$data = subsample_data()
  })
  
  esquisse_server(id = "esquisse", data_rv = data_rv)
}




shinyApp(ui, server)
```